# Perl Circle Array Function

Tags: arrays, perl

I am searching for help on how to loop  through an array. I have source code that takes a number for a radius of a circle and produces its circumference. This only takes one number, and I would like to get multiple circumferences.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;

$pi = 3.141592654;
print "What's the radius? ";
chomp($radius = <STDIN>);
$circle = 2 * $pi * $radius;
if ($radius < 0 ) {
$circle = 0;
}
print "The circumference of a circle with the radius of $radius is $circle.\n";
```

Now I want to be able to input several numbers for multiple radii using a while loop to put them into an array. Once I enter 0 or a number less than 0 the while loop will exit and the program will continue by looping through the array of user entered numbers and calculate the circumference of each circle using those values as a radii.

I have some code that is trying to do this, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
@number = <STDIN>;
while(<>) {
print "whats the radius? ";
my($circle, $radius, $pi);

$radius = &rad(<STDIN>);
$pi = 3.141592654;


$circle = 2 * $pi * $radius;
if ($radius <= 0){

    return $circle; }
}
```

Any direction of where to go, or a simple solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and to the [perl] tag! If you are learning Perl right now, it looks like you are using an out of date ressource. Please check out the tutorials linked in the [perl tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info) and improving by adding `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the top of every program you write. They will help you spot mistakes early.

Comment: Also note your second program is missing a `;` after the first line.

Answer (score 2):

To do that with an array, you need to first read until you get a zero and `push`. Then you can process the array using a `for` or `foreach` loop. Those two are the same, but the syntax commonly associated with `foreach`  is more perlish.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# turn on autoflush so stuff gets printed immediately
$|++;

print "Please enter a bunch of numbers, or 0 to stop. ";

my @numbers;
while ( my $n = <> ) {
    chomp $n;

    # stop at zero or less
    last if $n <= 0;

    # store the number in the array
    push @numbers, $n;
}

my $pi = 3.141592654;

foreach my $radius (@numbers) {
    my $circumference = 2 * $pi * $radius;

    # print with format (%s gets replaced by params)
    printf "The circumference of a circle with radius %s is %s\n", $radius, $circumference;
}
```

Here's the input/output.

```
Please enter a bunch of numbers, or 0 to stop. 1
2
3
0
The circumference of a circle with radius '1' is '6.283185308'
The circumference of a circle with radius '2' is '12.566370616'
The circumference of a circle with radius '3' is '18.849555924'
```

When running your first program, I noticed that the *What's the radius?* message showed up under the input prompt. That is because your output buffer only gets flushed when you have a newline `\n` in the output (or in some other cases, but let's ignore those). To change that behaviour, you can enable autoflush on the buffer, or simply set [`$|`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to a value larger than zero. The increment-idiom is common to do that.

---

You can also use the Math::Trig module to get π. It comes with Perl and has a constant that gives you `pi`. Since constants in Perl are just subs, you import it like any other function from a module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::Trig 'pi'; # load module and import the 'pi' constant

# ...

foreach my $radius (@numbers) {
    my $circumference = 2 * pi * $radius;

    # print with format (%s gets replaced by params)
    printf "The circumference of a circle with radius %s is %s\n", $radius, $circumference;
}
```

Comment: `for` and `foreach` are exactly identical, aliases to the same function.

Comment: @simbabque Thank you this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
```

This repeats your code in a infinite loop, exiting if the radius <= `0`.

It stores all corresponding values for circle and radius in arrays:

```
my (@circle, @radius);
while(1){
    print "What's the radius? ";
    chomp($radius = <STDIN>);
    $circle = 2 * $pi * $radius;
    print "The circumference of a circle with the radius of $radius is $circle.\n";
    last if $radius <= 0;
    push @circle, $circle;
    push @radius, $radius;
}

print Dumper \@circle, \@radius;
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier than it might sound - tone of the key ways of interacting with an array is via a for (or foreach - they're the same) loop. Each iteration of the loop, a variable is set to the iterator - you can specify it (I have below) but if you don't it uses `$_` by default.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $PI = 3.141592654;

print "Please enter radii, terminate with ^D\n"; 
my @list_of_values = <STDIN>;
chomp ( @list_of_values ); #remove linefeeds

foreach my $radius ( @list_of_values ) { 
    print "Circumference of radius $radius is: ", $PI * $radius * 2,"\n"; 
}
```

The other trick I use above - is reading `STDIN`. Perl knows the difference between reading a single value - into a scalar - or reading a sequence of values into an array.

So it'll behave differently if you:

```
 my $value = <STDIN>; #reads one line
 my @values = <STDIN>; #reads all the lines
```

You could also do this with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $PI = 3.141592654;
my @list_of_values;

print "Enter radii, or \"done\" if complete\n";
while ( my $input = <STDIN> ) {
    chomp($input);
    last if $input eq "done";
    if ( $input =~ m/^[\d\.]+$/ ) {
        push( @list_of_values, $input );
    }
    else {
        print "Input of \"$input\" is invalid, please try again\n";
    }
}

foreach my $radius (@list_of_values) {
    print "Circumference of radius $radius is: ", $PI * $radius * 2, "\n";
}
```

`for` and `foreach` do the same thing, it's a matter of style which you use.